# Why is this a proof by contradiction for this algorithm? Isn't this a direct proof instead?

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, check-my-answer

**First Slide: Find Max(A)**

1. // INPUT: A[1..n] - an array of integers
2. // OUTPUT: an element m of A such that m >= A[j], for all 1 <= j <= A.length
3. max = A[j==1]
4. for j = 2 to A.length
5. if max < A[j]
6. max = A[j]
7. return max

**Second Slide: Proof By Contradiction**

Proof: Suppose the algorithm is incorrect. Then for some input A, either:

1. max is not an element of A or
2. A has an element A[j] such that max < A[j]

Max is initialized to and assigned to elements of A - so (1) is impossible.

After the j-th iteration of the for loop (lines 4 - 6), max >= A[j]. From lines 5,6 **max only increases**. Therefore upon termination, max >= A[j] which contradicts (2).

**End Of Slides**

This algorithm (first slide) finds the max element in the array. This is a proof by contradiction. Isn't this algorithm already proved when it gets to **max >= A[j] in the last line of the second slide**. Is **which contradicts (2)** even necessary? Because in the second slide you showed max is in the array, and then **you met the condition of a maxium m: an element m of A such
that m >= A[j] for all 1 <= j <= A.length.**

**This seems to be two proofs in one**. And since it seems to me that the direct proof happens first, then the proof by contradiction is redundant and therefore not necessary. **Am i missing something here? Is this only a proof by contradiction? Or is it a direct proof instead?**

**The image below is just the slides 1 and 2 that I transcribed above. From York University.**

[image: Find Max: Slides 1 and 2]

Comment: The proof assumes the opposite of what is to be proved then shows a contradiction. So it is a proof by contradiction. And so it is not a direct proof. It happens to prove that the algorithm is correct.  "when it gets to max >= A[j]" it has gotten there by having assumed the opposite of what is to be proved; it has not proved "max >= A[j]" having assumed nothing. Indeed since it assumed something that happens to be *false*, *anything* can be derived thereafter before discharging that assumption.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to think the structure of the proof is:

1. suppose the algorithm is incorrect;
2. prove that the algorithm is, in fact, correct;
3. this contradicts 1., so the algorithm is correct.

That's almost, but not quite true. Step 2 doesn't prove that the returned value $\mathrm{max}$ is bigger than every element of the array, which is what would be required to prove that the algorithm is correct. It just proves that $\mathrm{max}$ is bigger than the specific array value that was supposed to be a counterexample in step 1.

But, as [Yuval has pointed out](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/106023/9550), the proof is much easier if you forget about contradiction completely and prove that $\mathrm{max}$ is in the array (identical to the given proof) and then show that $\mathrm{max}$ is at least as big as every array element (identical to the proof except "for all $j$" instead of just for one supposed counterexample.

Comment: When it says "after the j-th iteration of the for-loop (lines 4 - 6)  max >=  A[j]" is it talking specifically about the index of the assumed counter example A[j]? When I initially read this proof I was thinking about j taking on all the values, so I was thinking at the end of each iteration max >= A[j]. And this is why I guess I was thinking along the lines of a direct proof.

Comment: @user100752 Yes, it's specifically the $j$ in point 2.

Answer (score 3):

It's a proof by contradiction that could easily be rewritten as a direct proof.

To rephrase it as a direct proof, we divide it into two claims:

1. $max$ is an element of $A$.
2. $max \geq A[j]$ for all $j$.

We can conclude that $max = \max(A)$.